# String manipulation in R with regex goes wrong

Tags: r, regex, stringr

From the string below I want to extract the following:

1. "Ja: Studiebesök"
   (Medfinansiering: *([^\r\n]+?)\r\n.)
2. "det är den delen som man saknar idag."
   ((?<=somatiska tillstånd)(.*)(?=Kommande))

My code below doesn't return anything. What am I doing wrong here?

```
string <- "Medfinansiering: Ja: Studiebesök\r\n Övriga synpunkter: Vi skulle anställa från Hermods YH utbildning som denna för den\r\n
är bred och ger oss kompetent personal med helhetssyn och\r\n kunskap om somatisk tillstånd, det är den delen som man saknar\r\n idag. Kommande pensionsavgångar leder till att vi behöver\r\n nyrekrytera och den andra hälften av rekryteringsbehovet beror\r\n"

str_match_all(string, regex("Medfinansiering: *([^\\r\\n]+?)\\r\\n.*?(?<=somatiska tillstånd)(.*)(?=Kommande)", dotall=T))[[1]][,-1]
```

Comment: You have a different literal string there, you search for `somatiska` but there is `somatisk` in the string. Check `str_match_all(string, "(?s)Medfinansiering: *([^\r\n]+)\r\n.*?(somatisk tillstånd.*)(?=Kommande)")[[1]][,-1] `

Comment: oh my I'm blind. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In two steps:

```
string <- "Medfinansiering: Ja: Studiebesök\r\n Övriga synpunkter: Vi skulle anställa från Hermods YH utbildning som denna för den\r\n
är bred och ger oss kompetent personal med helhetssyn och\r\n kunskap om somatisk tillstånd, det är den delen som man saknar\r\n idag. Kommande pensionsavgångar leder till att vi behöver\r\n nyrekrytera och den andra hälften av rekryteringsbehovet beror\r\n"

sub("\\\r.*", "", string)
sub("\r\n", "", sub(".*tillstånd. *(.*?) *Kommande.*", "\\1", string))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `somatiska` with `somatisk` in the pattern, and you can simplify the pattern by moving the lookbehind pattern into the second capturing group, i.e. `(?<=somatiska tillstånd)(.*)` to `(somatiska tillstånd.*)`.

You can use

```r
str_match_all(string, "(?s)Medfinansiering: *([^\r\n]+)\r\n.*?(somatisk tillstånd.*)(?=Kommande)")[[1]][,-1]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sZqU6R/1).

**Details**

- `(?s)` - the `dotall` inline modifier
- `Medfinansiering:` - a literal text
- `*` - zero or more spaces (use `\h*` or `[\p{Zs}\t]*` to match any horizontal whitespace)
- `([^\r\n]+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than CR and LF
- `\r\n` - a CLRF ending
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(somatisk tillstånd.*)`  - Group 2: `somatisk tillstånd` and then any 0+ chars as many as possible till...
- `(?=Kommande)` - up to the last occurrence of `Kommande`.